# Difficult to understand the total number of page request & application support for how many users?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

In my environment, home page consist the 60 page requests (seen in ff firebug) & display same as 60 samples while recording the script of home page in jmeter.

suppose i have taken,

```
Number of threads ( users ) = 10, 
Ramp-up period = 1, 
loop count = 1
```

Then my question is that the total number of `page requests are = 10 * 60 = 600 or 10` ? & my application support for how much `user 600 or 10`?

Thanks in advance for answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Total page requests will be 600, no. of requests in test plan * no. of users.
- Does your application support 600 or 10 users??

  - If you do not have any error, your application will at least supports 10 users.

Please read these articles to understand how you can use jMeter.

http://nico.vahlas.eu/2010/03/17/some-thoughts-on-stress-testing-web-applications-with-jmeter-part-1/

http://nico.vahlas.eu/2010/03/30/some-thoughts-on-stress-testing-web-applications-with-jmeter-part-2/

Comment: thanks manish, do you mean total number of users doesn't depend upon total number of page requests?

Comment: your question is not clear to me, but I think you believe Total number of request divided by no. of users should give you capacity. However all the samplers in a TestPlan are executed sequentially. So jmeter is sending only "no. of user" requests simultaneously to SUT. So effective simultaneous request you might see could be only N, no. of users. Though based on your response time that number can vary.

Comment: @ManishSapariya, I'm also working on jmeter now and I saw your answer, but the links you posted were broken, do you have any other references?